# Running Gradle on macbook

Tags: macos, gradle, gradlew

I have recently bought a macbook and tried to install Gradle with brew install gradle

When I do gradle -v I get my Gradle specifications with no problem, bit when I try to run a Gradle task on my project I got this error:

org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.getClassesDir()Ljava/io/File;

On windows I usually compile the project by doing ./gradlew task_name, but the ./gradlew isn't working here on Mac OS.

What Im I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`SourceSetOutput.getClassesDir()` was deprecated in Gradle 4 and removed in Gradle 5. It's now `SourceSetOutput.getClassesDirs()`. I'm guessing you are running a newer version of Gradle on the macbook than you were running on the Windows box. A simple fix is to downgrade the Gradle version.

If you want to actually fix your build to work with Gradle 5+ I suggest you run with `--stacktrace` on the command line to find out what's using the old API (ie if it's your Gradle script or one of your plugins).

Perhaps a fix is as simple as upgrading one or two of your plugins to a new version which supports Gradle 5+